# Screen magnification for linux

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, accessibility

I have a coworker that is VI (visually impaired) and that is also trying to immerse himself in the Linux world. He uses a product on windows named ZoomText made by freedom scientific. He uses different levels of magnification for different screens on this product. and has been doing so for many years.

We have researched some, and seem to find no comparable analog in Linux land.

The closest we have been able to come thus far is using KDE magnifier + some clever window manipulation to make one screen normal and the other full screen magnification clone of the first, somewhat achieving a pseudo work around. But the desired effect is to have the ability to zoom in and out of each screen (2 or more) independent of one another and use BOTH screens as real estate, not have to sacrifice one for the other, or magnify both at the same level.

Before we go off reinventing the wheel, or marching into a wall, just curious if any other VI users out there (or admins that support them) have crossed this bridge and have suggestions on what to try, or specifically what has been tried and will not work?

Edit:
Added example of what we have been targeting thus far, built off work of others and some experimentation:

```
#!/bin/bash
kmag & sleep 5
xprop -id "$(wmctrl -l | grep 'KMagnifier' | awk '{ print $1 }')" -set WM_NAME "KMagnifier"
xprop -name "KMagnifier" -f _MOTIF_WM_HINTS 32c -set _MOTIF_WM_HINTS "0x2, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0"
xprop -f _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE 32a -name "KMagnifier" -set _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DOCK
wmctrl -r "KMagnifier" -e 0,0,-38,1933,450
xprop -f _NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL 32c -name "KMagnifier" -set _NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL " 0, 0, 0, 72, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1024"
```

Basically start a new KMag instance, hide parts, change its window style, dock it, and sets its HxW to screen size (In this example only 450px high because I am currently on laptop)

Using this we can dock an instance to be screen sized, on left monitor and magnify right, but to get 2 monitors magnified would require 4, not practical so we scrapped the idea all together. It does not really track as well, and you can drag things under the magnifier on far left screen, etc...

So the ultimate hope is someone with far more experience than either of us in Linux could similarly brew up a solution that we could learn from and build upon.

Comment: Though it will only magnify within some applications, not the "ornaments", e.g., title or menus, *CTRL - Mouse Wheel* is a common convention for zooming in and out. Ubuntu also has Accessibility features, https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/a11y.html.en , e.g.,  Change text size and magnify a screen area.

Comment: Yes the problem with that is with multiple screens, the "zoom" does every screen at the same time. The desire is for instance to have screen left be at 4x while screen right may be at 9x, and have the screen either scroll at boundaries, or scroll around cursor while centered. The same as zoom works in Ubuntu, but independently on each display attached.

Comment: Have you seen [Virtual Magnifying Glass](https://magnifier.sourceforge.net/)? The documentation seems promising.

Comment: Yes we have, and the several other magnifiers offer a lens mode as well.  We have several magnification options, we are looking to see if anyone has any experience with or knows of something we cannot find/create that does independent full screen magnification. TBH we know it is a long shot, because we have been searching ourselves. But when we cobbled together the full screen docked KMag, it was a glimmer of hope someone else may have tinkered and discovered things we had not thought of yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as an update to assist anyone that may have this issue, in the future. We settled on a nicely functional solution. IN this case we are using mint, but should work on any mate environment. By installing Compiz and enabling the "Enhanced Zoom"

It allows for complete independent desktop zooms.
To keep from one panning all the way left or right when transitioning monitors, we then bound a hotkey to xdotool, issuing commands to move to center of the other desktop, so you can position one the way you want it, zoomed to what you need it to be, then keystroke to other monitor (xdotool mouse move, does not trigger mouse track in zoomed window!)

End result, one happy Jr. SysAdmin, now able to fluently function in a Linux desktop environment... WIN!

I sincerely hope this assists someone else in the future facing the same challenges.